# Primefaces schedule not autoscrolling in top

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, schedule, autoscroll

I am using primefaces schedule, when i drag the event on top it didn't scroll automatically to top. i have to manually scroll top and then drag to event to place on top.

```
<pou:schedule id="schedule-1" 
      value="#{scheduleMb.scheduleModel}" 
      widgetVar="schedule"
      view="agendaWeek"
      slotMinutes="15"
      rendered="#{authorizationUtilMb.hasPermission('d3v4951s')}"> 

---------
=-------
-----
other code
<pou:schedule>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]
under thu 1/28 i am dragging the image to top. you can see.